# Does webpack not write to disc?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to get webpack bundle working with my node.js application, but I cant seem to find the physical webpack bundle. Is there even one?
I'm familiar with gulp where it outputs a bundle into a folder you specifically choose, but I cant get it to work with webpack.
docs aren't that helpful either

Comment: Webpack keeps the bundle in memory I'm pretty sure, that is what makes it fast for hot-reloads.

Comment: @TrevorHutto Where does it do that tho? if I search my application folder I never find a bundle file.

Comment: You cannot view memory directly, you only see files written to disk in your folders. This may help https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/62

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Care to post your Webpack config?

Generally speaking, your Webpack config will specify, at minimum, an 'entry' and an 'output'; it will start with your entry (typically an app.js file), do all the bundling and output the resulting bundle where you tell it via 'output' (usually a file that lives in a 'dist' folder that is then run inside of your index.html to produce your app!).

If you're using hot-reloading, then the bundle is in memory only and that's why it's typical to have a 'dev' webpack config and a 'production' config with only the latter writing to disk.

For example, just a basic config with no hot reloading:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: __dirname + '/src/js/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: __dirname + '/src/js/app-bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'sourcemap'
}
```

output can take a number of options: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html

hope that helps!